# Обработка ошибки Mongoose используя Async

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Решил вместо колбеков использовать async/await, но как-то не пошло.
В общем-то есть метод `create` у модели пользователя, который хеширует пароль и создаёт запись в БД, если пользователя с таким именем нет.

Суть ошибки: В контроллере обрабатываю с помощью Catch создание пользователя, но ошибку он выдаёт именно в консоли ноды и catch не работает

Контроллер

```
const User = require('../models/User');

exports.index = async (req, res) => {
    const user = new User({
        name: req.body.name,
        password: req.body.password
    });
    try {
        await User.create(user);
        await res.json({
            success: true,
            message: "Пользователь успешно создан"
        })
    } catch (e) {
        await res.json({
            success: false,
            message: "Что-то пошло не так"
        });
    }

};
```

Модель

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        length: 40,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});

const User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

module.exports.create = (user) => {
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function (err, salt) {
        bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, function (err, hash) {
            if (err) throw err;
            user.password = hash;
            return user.save();
        });
    });
};

module.exports.getByName = (name, callback) => {
    User.findOne({name}, callback);
};
```

Comment: `module.exports.create` не асинхронная же. и ошибка происходит у неё внутри

Comment: @nörbörnën а как сделать так, чтобы ошибка не происходила у неё внутри?

Comment: можно переписать её по-асинхронному. или хотя бы в обоих колбеках поставить вывод ошибок в консоль

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо @nörbörnën за помощь!

Переписал функцию по асинхронному и всё заработало

```
module.exports.create = async (user) => {
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, 12);
    const newUser = new User({ name: user.name, password: hashedPassword });
    await user.save();
};
```

Comment: хорошо, что справился сам. но функцию нужно довести до ума: сейчас в аргументах она получает инстанс User-а, создаёт новый инстанс, сохраняет пришедший. и ещё, возможно было бы правильнее чтобы она что-то возвращала (заменить `await user.save();` на `return user.save();` или `await user.save(); return user/newUser;`)